# How to divide columns of matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

I have a matrix `X` of size `[N, D1]` , and I want to obtain a new matrix `X2 [N2, D2]`, where the output `X2` should look like this :

```
f(X,D2) = X2 =

[ part 1 of X(1,:)   === X(1, 1 : D2)
  part 2 of X(1,:)   === X(1, D2+1 : 2*D2) , etc
  ...
  part K of X(1,:)
  part 1 of X(2,:)
  ...
  ...
  part K of X(N,:) ]
```

so `D2` will be supplied such that `mod(D1,D2)=0;` Therefore, `N2 = N * D1/D2`.

I couldn't make `reshape` work for this purpose. Maybe I can do this with a for loop but I wonder if there is a vectorized / efficient way for this.

Thanks for any help!

### Example input

```
X = [1, 2, 3, 4,  5,  6
     7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Which has 6 columns, so I want to divide it into columns of 3:

```
f(X,3) = [1,2,3
          4,5,6
          7,8,9
            ...]
```

Comment: I suggest adding a simple numerical example (input and desired output) to your question to make sure that everybody understand exactly what you are asking.

Comment: @Hoki good suggestion, doing it right now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. It was as simple as transposing, reshaping and then transposing again.

So for my example, the solution would be:

```
X2 = reshape(X',3,[])';
```

Sorry for such a simple question, but I will still keep it in case it helps others too.

Comment: good job! You can accept your own answer to close the thread.

Comment: Thanks :) Yep, I tried but it says "you can accept your answer in 2 days". So we wait..